# How to catch exception occured in DAL of ObjectDataSource object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have ObjectDataSource and GridView on one of the pages of my asp.net web project.

To initialize ObjectDataSource i use Init event:

```
   protected void ObjectDataSource1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ObjectDataSource1.EnablePaging = true;
            ObjectDataSource1.TypeName = "CustomerDataSource";
            ObjectDataSource1.DataObjectTypeName = "Customer";
            ObjectDataSource1.SelectMethod = "GetCustomers";
            ObjectDataSource1.UpdateMethod = "Update";
            ObjectDataSource1.SelectCountMethod = "GetCustomersCount";
            ObjectDataSource1.MaximumRowsParameterName = "maximumRows";
            ObjectDataSource1.StartRowIndexParameterName = "startRowIndex";

      }
```

Somewhere in DAL:

```
public static List<Customer> GetCustomers(int maximumRows, int startRowIndex)
{
   try {
         ... some select to database here...
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
         Utils.LogError(ex);
         throw ex;
       }
}
```

Now let's imagine that GetCustomers for some reason throws an exception. How could i catch this exception and handle it? I know i can use Application_Error, but i would like to catch this exception somehow on my page and show some friendly message to the user. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: You should use "throw;" and not "throw ex;". The former will retain the stack from where the exception was originally thrown, whilst the latter replaces it with the stack for GetCustomers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try handling the relevant `ObjectDataSource` event.

In your example, the `Selected` event, but there are also `Inserted`, `Updated` and `Deleted` events that you handle in the same way.

The events provide an `ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs` which has the `Exception`, and a property `ExceptionHandled` that you can set to indicate you have handled the exception (for example, displaying an error message).

There are some samples in MSDN.

Comment: Thanks! That's what i wanted!